# Matlab how to switch multi-dimensional image dimensions

Tags: matlab

For example, there is a matrix `M` with the size of `(m,n,j,p,k,i)` , how to change it to the matrix with the size of `(m,n,p,j,k,i)` .
I tried using `reshape.m`:

```
M2 = reshape(M,[m,n,p,j,k,i])
```

But the result is not what I intended. Is there some specialized function to switch the image dimensions, that is, between the 3rd and 4th dimensions here?

```
for s = 1:j
   for t = 1:p
      M2(:,:,t,s,:,:) = M(:,:,s,t,:,:)
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `permute.m`

```
M2 = permute(M,[1,2,4,3,5,6])
```